# Component inside ng-content not load with custom Element Angular

Tags: angular, custom-element, angular-elements, angular2-ngcontent

I'm having a little problem with Angular Elements, here an exemple :

I have custom element with this selector "custom" and this template :

`<ng-content><ng-content>`

I have a component (not custom) with this selector "component" and this template :
`<p> Hello Word </p>`

and in my page my custom element looks like this :

```
<custom>
     <!-- some HTML -->
     <component></component>
      <!-- some HTML -->
</custom>
```

my custom element work fine but my component is never load like is not interpreted by angular

Have you any idea why ? and how to do this ?

Comment: That is indeed not possible. Your `component` should be made a custom element as well

Comment: Ok but I want to communicate between this two component this possible if they are both custom element ?

Comment: You are better of making one bigger angular element, which have both these components. Or if there is a limited set of components, you can make it some sort of input on the parent to decide which child to render